# How to add a newer version of PHP and MySQL to WAMP 2.1 without reinstalling WAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

WAMP's website states that additional versions of Apache, PHP, or MySQL can be added to a current WAMP 2.1 instance, but I don't know how to go about doing it. In my case, reinstalling WAMP is not an option.

Comment: One of the countless situations where an operating with a SoftwareManagement system like Linux solves such tasks with literally a few mouse clicks.

Comment: You can follow this answer for adding PHP version https://superuser.com/a/569472

Comment: WAMPServer 2.1 has been dead for many years. What versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL are you currently using

Comment: What versions of MySQL and PHP are you trying to move to?